# How to avoid SQL server time out issue while handling huge amount of data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc

I have to handle a huge amount of data in my ASP.Net MVC application. Sometimes there is timeout while retrieving data. Which are all known methods to speed up the execution and avoid time out? The application uses SQL SPs.

The following query in SP takes more time.

```
WITH CTESelect AS (
  SELECT  TOP 20 CompanyName
  FROM    Periodicals P
  WHERE   P.PID IN (
            SELECT  DISTINCT CASE WHEN P.ParentID IS NULL 
                             THEN P.PID
                             ELSE P.ParentID
                             END AS PID
            FROM    Periodicals P
                    LEFT JOIN Companies C ON P.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
                    LEFT JOIN UserContacts UC ON P.CreatedUserID = UC.UserID
                    LEFT JOIN Contacts CT ON UC.ContactID = CT.ContactID
                    LEFT JOIN UserContacts URC ON P.CustomerID = URC.UserID
                    LEFT JOIN Contacts RCT ON URC.ContactID = RCT.ContactID
                    LEFT JOIN UserRepresentCompanies UCP ON UCP.UserID = URC.UserID
                    LEFT JOIN Contacts CC ON CC.ContactID = UCP.CompanyContactID
            WHERE   ( @CompanyID IS NULL OR @CompanyID = C.CompanyID )
                    AND ( @CustomerID = 0 OR @CustomerID = URC.UserID )
                    AND ( P.SaveMode IS NULL )
          )
)
SELECT  DISTINCT  CompanyName
FROM    CTESelect
```

Comment: Simplest solution: don't select as many rows (and columns)...... other solutions: use proper indices to speed up your queries, increase the timeout, do the processing on the server instead of pulling down huge amounts of data to the client, ....

Comment: OK that's the query - what do the tables look like, and which columns are already indexed??

Comment: @Prasanth - You are selecting at most 20 records. That is not a *huge amount of data*. If this query is taking a lot of time, you are most likely missing various indexes.

Comment: @Lieven - I meant the huge amount of data in Periodicals table. I select the companyname from this data

Comment: @marc_s P.PID, P.CreatedUserID, P.CustomerID, Companies.CompanyID are indexed

Comment: @Prasanth - that is why you should post all relevant data. Before you posted the query, I (and likely many others) assumed you were returning a lot of data. That is *very* different from selecting data from a huge table but only returning 20 records. Knowing the latter, we can already dismiss network latency among other things

Comment: @Prasanth - could you post your execution plan?

Comment: @Lieven Yes, I need to retrieve only 20 records from the table which contains a lakhs of records and according to the specified conditions

Comment: @Prasanth - how about the execution plan?

Comment: @Lieven - The execution plan costs more for the Users table because it has relationships with many other tables

Comment: @Prasanth - no offense but without you posting an execution plan , all we can do is take a guess at it or look into our crystal bal. Mine has been broken for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, selecting at most 20 records should not take a huge amount of time.

#### Some things to verify

- does each `foreign key` have an index
- is there a covering  index on `SaveMode` and `companyname`

Sidenote: It seems to me your SQL Statement could be simplified to the following. Only change in output should be that there are *always* 20 records selected whereas that might not have been the case in your original query.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  TOP 20 DISTINCT COALESCE(Pp.CompanyName, p.CompanyName)
FROM    Periodicals P
        LEFT JOIN Periodicals Pp ON Pp.PID = P.ParentID
        LEFT JOIN Companies C ON P.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
        LEFT JOIN UserContacts UC ON P.CreatedUserID = UC.UserID
        LEFT JOIN Contacts CT ON UC.ContactID = CT.ContactID
        LEFT JOIN UserContacts URC ON P.CustomerID = URC.UserID
        LEFT JOIN Contacts RCT ON URC.ContactID = RCT.ContactID
        LEFT JOIN UserRepresentCompanies UCP ON UCP.UserID = URC.UserID
        LEFT JOIN Contacts CC ON CC.ContactID = UCP.CompanyContactID
WHERE   ( @CompanyID IS NULL OR @CompanyID = C.CompanyID )
        AND ( @CustomerID = 0 OR @CustomerID = URC.UserID )
        AND ( P.SaveMode IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 1):

First do you need LEFT joins for each table?  If some of those can be changed to inner joins that'll help.  Make sure that you have index everywhere that you need them.  You'll want to check the execution plan to insure that you have everything indexed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

optimize your stored proc. there are a million pages on this on google.

if you can't, then increase the timeout value in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most definitely with the query.

A few things of notice.

You are doing multiple joins to the same tables for different fields
If you did these in one join as opposed to an entire table lookup/scan would be more efficient

e.g

```
 LEFT JOIN UserContacts UC ON UC.UserID = P.CreatedUserID
 AND UC.UserID = P.CustomerID
 LEFT JOIN Contacts CT ON CT.ContactID = UC.ContactID 
 AND CT.ContactID = UC.ContactID
```

Also noticed that P.CustomerId = UserID? Is that a valid relationship? as that would make 2 joins to the UserContacts table to the Periodicals Table on the same field. You may get away with only 1 join

```
LEFT JOIN UserContacts URC ON P.CustomerID = URC.UserID
```

You may also be returning extra tables of data in the join for no output reason e.g why is UserRepresentCompanies in the query? You aren't seleting data from it or using in where clause.

Comment: The query specified is a partial query and there are many types of users in Users table so sometimes we need more than one joins to the same table

Comment: If you run query in Management Studio on it's own how long does it take to run? Take ASP.NET MVC out of the equation as it's only getting 20 rows back and just extending connection time is not a viable solution.